# Validating query params from ?d_from[abc]=123&d_to[abc]=234 in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to support query parameters representing a date range for a date field where there may be more than one date field (but only one per request).

I can validate all other query parameters just fine using my DTO class but can't work out how to define the decorators.

Here's my DTO class:

```js
export class CustomerPaymentQueryParamDto extends RequestQueryModel {
    @Transform(({ value: it }: { value: string }) => Number.parseInt(it))
    @IsOptional()
    @Min(1)
    public readonly page_number?: number

    @Transform(({ value: it }: { value: string }) => Number.parseInt(it))
    @IsOptional()
    @Min(1)
    public readonly page_size?: number

    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    public readonly filter?: string

    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    public readonly sortBy?: string

    @Transform(({ value: it }: { value: string }) => (isString(it) && ['true', 'false'].includes(it.toLowerCase()) ? it.toLowerCase() === 'true' : it))
    @IsOptional()
    @IsBoolean()
    public readonly descending?: boolean

    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => DateFromTo)
    @ValidateNested()
    public readonly d_from?: DateFromTo

    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => DateFromTo)
    @ValidateNested()
    public readonly d_to?: DateFromTo
    :
```

Here's my `DateFromTo` class:

```js
import { IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator'

export class DateFromTo {
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    payment_date?: string

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    create_date?: string

    public constructor(paymentDate: string | undefined, createDate: string | undefined) {
        this.payment_date = paymentDate
        this.create_date = createDate
    }
}
```

When I submit a request such as:

```
/payments?d_from[payment_date]=2018-08-01&d_to[payment_date]=2018-08-03&page_number=1&page_size=10
```

I get an error:

```
  code: ErrorCode {
    key: 'validation.invalid_query_parameter',
    message: "The value for the query parameter 'd_from[payment_date]' is invalid",
    httpStatus: 400
  },
```

I tried dumping out various bits from nest's validation.pipe.js just before it throws the error:

```
value: {"d_from[payment_date]":"2018-08-01","d_to[payment_date]":"2018-08-03","page_number":"1","page_size":"10"}, meta: undefined, val: {"forbidUnknownValues":true,"whitelist":true,"forbidNonWhitelisted":true,"validationError":{"target":true}}, entity: {"page_number":1,"page_size":10,"d_from[payment_date]":"2018-08-01","d_to[payment_date]":"2018-08-03"}, class: CustomerPaymentQueryParamDto, errors: [{"target":{"page_number":1,"page_size":10,"d_from[payment_date]":"2018-08-01","d_to[payment_date]":"2018-08-03"},"value":"2018-08-01","property":"d_from[payment_date]","constraints":{"whitelistValidation":"property d_from[payment_date] should not exist"}},{"target":{"page_number":1,"page_size":10,"d_from[payment_date]":"2018-08-01","d_to[payment_date]":"2018-08-03"},"value":"2018-08-03","property":"d_to[payment_date]","constraints":{"whitelistValidation":"property d_to[payment_date] should not exist"}}]
```

I'm hoping it can transform the `d_from` and `d_to` values from the query string into:

```
d_from: { payment_date: '2018-08-01' }, d_to: { payment_date: '2018-08-03' }
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case and created a library for parameter-based filtering in NestJS.
Here is the link to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/KartikyaThakur/nestjs-query-filter) and the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kartikyathakur/nestjs-query-filter).

Particularly [this file](https://github.com/KartikyaThakur/nestjs-query-filter/blob/main/src/utilities/filter-request-helper.ts), where I transform the query parameters to the corresponding ORM or Array filter.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks !! I found the error was coming from the global validation pipe, and then discovered there is no way to override the global pipe at the endpoint level. I ended up solving my problem by:

* creating my own class that extends the nest `ValidationPipe`
* include logic to 'expand' query parameters in the format `filter[some_field]=some_value`
* use my new class in the global validation pipe instead of the standard one

Sorry about the crappy formatting. I tried to make the above a list but couldn't work out how :)